# Java - How to check if the queue of type ArrayBlockedQueue of LinkedList

Tags: java, arraylist, queue

if my method is accepting Queues from any type, how to determine if the method arg is ArrayBlockedQueue()  or LinkedList() queue?

I used `.equals` as the following its always returning `true`

```
Queue q1 = new LinkedList();
Queue q2 = new ArrayBlockingQueue(4);
System.out.println(l1.equals(q1));
```

then I tried the following I have faced Illegal argument exception

```
public static void add2Q (Queue q)  {
    if(q.equals( new ArrayBlockingQueue(q.size()))){
        q.offer(2);
        q.offer(5);
        q.offer(9);
        q.offer(0);
        q.offer(-1);
    } else {
        // thorws exception with add if exceeded 
        try {
            q.add(2);
            q.add(5);
            q.add(4);
            q.add(9);
            q.add(10);
        } catch (IllegalStateException e){
            System.out.println("you are using ArrayBlockQueue of size "+ q.size() );
            //e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }   
}
```

Comment: Why? You should not care. That's the whole point of being passed a `Queue` object instead of a specific type.

Comment: @EJP this is only for the sake of examining which method to use when adding element to the Queue

Answer (score 0):

If you want to determine the type of object:

```
if (l1 instanceof LinkedList) {
   //Do something
}
```

The same solution will apply for other objects as well.